# Mongoose Schema reference one to many

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, relationship

i want to build a one to many reference with Mongoose, but i dont want to keep a list of ids.

What i have:

**menuCategorySchema**

```
var schema = new Schema({
    menuItem: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'menuItem'
    }],
    icon: String,
    name: String
});
```

**menuItemSchema**

```
var schema = new Schema({
    menuCategory: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'menuCategory'
    },
    name: String,
    path: String
});
```

**Mongo Collection menuItem:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54be856e9ba3a972e4dc924e"),
    "menuCategory" : ObjectId("54be84919ba3a972e4dc924d"),
    "name" : "I am a menu item",
    "path" : "/item/path"
}
```

**Mongo Collection menuCategory:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54be84919ba3a972e4dc924d"),
    "icon" : "awsome",
    "name" : "Main Category"
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
var menuCategory = require('./models/menuCategory');
menuCategory.find({}).populate('menuItem').exec(function(err,result){
    console.log(result);
})

{
    "_id": ObjectId("54be84919ba3a972e4dc924d"),
    "icon": "awsome",
    "name": "Main Category"
    "menuItem": [{
        "_id": ObjectId("54be856e9ba3a972e4dc924e"),
        "menuCategory": ObjectId("54be84919ba3a972e4dc924d"),
        "name": "I am a menu item",
        "path": "/item/path"
    }]
}
```

I was able to populate the **menuItem** with **menuCategory** but i would like the other way around.

Comment: Unless you store the array of ObjectIds in menuItem in the menuCategory collection, I don't see how you can do this.

Comment: This should be pretty simple, just find and populate every item using the category id. I guess mongoose dont have any implementation for that